# Getting rid of space around flashcards in the flashcard class

Tags: margins, flashcards

Consider the sample document given in the (chapter 3) of the [documentation](http://ftp.uni-erlangen.de/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/flashcards/flashcards.pdf) of the `flashcards` class.

```
\documentclass[avery5388,grid,frame]{flashcards}
\cardfrontstyle[\large\slshape]{headings}
\cardbackstyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\cardfrontfoot{Functional Analysis}
\begin{flashcard}[Definition]{Norm on a Linear Space \\ Normed Space}
A linear/vector space with a norm is called a \emph{normed}
\end{flashcard}

\begin{flashcard}[Definition]{Inner Product}
  Let $X$ be a complex linear space. An \emph{inner product} a mapping that associates to each pair of vectors $x$, $y$ denoted $(x,y)$, that satisfies Additivity, Homogeneity, Symmetry and positive Definiteness.
\end{flashcard}
\end{document}
```

When printing those flashcards I don't want to spend extra time also cutting of the extra white space around the flashcards themselves.

However, trying to reduce the margins with the `geometry` package clashes with the class options, since it already uses this package and `\setlength{\textheight}{854}` also doesn't help.
How can I tackle this problem?

**Edit:** It would also suffice if all margins would be the same length, then I could just enlarge the document before printing, effectively getting rid of the white space, too.

Comment: It'd be a good idea to reproduce the example in your post so people don't have to hunt for and cut out the line numbers in that example.

Comment: @JPi I edited. Is this want you wanted?

Comment: The package is designed to print onto sheets of cards, e.g the [Avery 5388](https://www.avery.com/products/cards/5388)  so you shouldn't need to do any cutting other than at the perforations. If you don't like the frame, just remove the frame option.

Comment: @AlanMunn I want to print on regular A4 paper, do I just remove the Avery option or do I have to do something else?

Comment: If you look at section 4 of the documentation it shows you how to create your own card paper configuration file.

Comment: @AlanMunn Just to verify that there's no misunderstanding: I am not interested in changing the format of the cards themselves but I want no margins on the a4 paper I am printing them onto, i.e the frame of the cards should be the edge of the paper.

Comment: Yes so you need to build your own paper configuration file to do that.

Comment: @AlanMunn In Overleaf, I managed to get want I want (on screen) with ```\setlength{\cardheight}{55.5mm} 
\setlength{\cardwidth}{107.55mm}

\geometry{\cardpapermode,
 \cardpaper,
 top=-3.2mm,
 left=0cm,
 right=0cm,
bottom=0cm,
noheadfoot}```, but I don't know how this fits the 297 * 210 mm size A4 paper with 10 cards per page. The math doesn't check out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://osl.ugr.es/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/flashcards/flashcards.pdf), you have one option `\setlength{\cardmargin}{0 pt}` on page ten that allows you to change the margins.

Edit: Update the answer with the info in the comments.

You can set the margins of the paper and the size of the card according to the paper so that you have no margins.
Below there's the code that fits 3 cards in one A4-size paper without any margins.

```
\documentclass[avery5388,grid,frame]{flashcards}
\cardfrontstyle[\large\slshape]{headings}
\cardbackstyle{empty}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
        a4paper,
        total={210mm,297mm},
        left=0mm,
        top=0mm,
}
%
\setlength{\cardheight}{99mm}  % 99=297/3
\setlength{\cardwidth}{210mm}
\setlength{\topskip}{0mm}
%

\begin{document}
\cardfrontfoot{Functional Analysis}
\begin{flashcard}[Definition]{Inner Product}
Let $X$ be a complex linear space. An \emph{inner product} a mapping that associates to each pair of vectors $x$, $y$ denoted $(x,y)$, that satisfies Additivity, Homogeneity, Symmetry and positive definiteness.
\end{flashcard}
\begin{flashcard}[Definition]{Inner Product}
Let $X$ be a complex linear space. An \emph{inner product} a mapping that associates to each pair of vectors $x$, $y$ denoted $(x,y)$, that satisfies Additivity, Homogeneity, Symmetry and positive definiteness.
\end{flashcard}
\begin{flashcard}[Definition]{Inner Product}
Let $X$ be a complex linear space. An \emph{inner product} a mapping that associates to each pair of vectors $x$, $y$ denoted $(x,y)$, that satisfies Additivity, Homogeneity, Symmetry and positive definiteness.
\end{flashcard}
\end{document}
```

If you use a different paper size, you can adjust it in the options of the `geometry` package.

Comment: Updated the answer with \topskip set up to 0, and increased the length of the cards. Now it fills up the page.